# What kind of TypeError is that?

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

Does anybody understand the mistake regarding this code? It seems to be a problem with last row of code.

**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'**

```
BS = requests.get(f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/balance-sheet-statement/{company}?apikey={demo}').json()

# get income statement as % of revenue for future predictions and forecast 5 next IS years
income_statement = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(IS[0], orient='index')
income_statement = income_statement[5:26]
income_statement.columns = ['current_year']
income_statement['as_%_of_revenue'] = income_statement /income_statement.iloc[0]
```

if i change the code

```
income_statement['as_%_of_revenue'] = income_statement /income_statement.iloc[0]
```

to int, its afterwards giving me

```
 income_statement['as_%_of_revenue'] = int((income_statement) / int(income_statement)).iloc[0]
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DataFrame'
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and post a [mre]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in the last row?

Comment: Can you add what your dataframe look like?

Comment: hey @PrakashDahal yes sure i will explain as an answer below because its clearer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Although a bit more research could've probably solved this question:

You are trying to divide two numbers (I guess) but they are formatted as `str`. Try to convert them to something that is divisible, like `int` or `float`, simple example:

```
**income_statement['as_%_of_revenue'] = int(income_statement) / int(income_statement.iloc[0]**)
```

### Update

It seems you are trying to divide a value from a row in a pandas Dataframe by another number from that row. If you have the Dataframe
`df = pd.DataFrame(data=([100, 200], [500, 500]))`:

```
     0    1
0  100  200
1  500  500
```

You can add a column containing the percentage of first over second column like this: 
`df['as_%'] = (df[0] / df[1])*100`. This results in:

```
     0    1   as_%
0  100  200   50.0
1  500  500  100.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately not soling the problem..i tried before

Comment: You have to check what the type is of the two numbers you are trying to divide. Your error comes from the fact you are trying to divide numbers which are actually formatted as strings. Try printing the types of your variables using `type(income_statement)` and  `type(income_statement.iloc[0]**)` and make sure they are not `str`.

Comment: its a class because its framed before: income_statement = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(IS[0], orient='index')

Comment: in my opinion that would work if if would have to columns two calculate with. Unfortunately i just have 1 column ["current year"] anyway thanks a lot for your help and time, i appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

this line was missing

```
net_income = IS[0]['netIncome']
```

thats why the question "what i want to achieve with the last row was unclear". Hence the whole code is:

```
net_income = IS[0]['netIncome']

BS = requests.get(f'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/balance-sheet-statement/{company}?apikey={demo}').json()
    
    # get income statement as % of revenue for future predictions and forecast 5 next IS years
    income_statement = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(IS[0], orient='index')
    income_statement = income_statement[5:26]
    income_statement.columns = ['current_year']
    income_statement['as_%_of_revenue'] = income_statement /income_statement.iloc[0]
```

What i want to achieve with this is to divide the income_statement by the revenues(sales) = income/revenue (both current year). The result shall give me a Percentage of Revenue to Forecast the next Years, its a Multiplicator.

The Data before dividing it looks like this.

The problem is that income_statement is defined as a class because of the dataframe

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

                                 current_year
period                                     FY
revenue                             495308000
costOfRevenue                        43839000
grossProfit                         451469000
grossProfitRatio                     0.911491
researchAndDevelopmentExpenses      101117000
generalAndAdministrativeExpenses    101439000
sellingAndMarketingExpenses         252820000
otherExpenses                               0
operatingExpenses                   455376000
costAndExpenses                     499215000
interestExpense                      38119000
depreciationAndAmortization          12101000
ebitda                              8.194e+06
ebitdaratio                         0.0165432
operatingIncome                    -3.907e+06
operatingIncomeRatio              -0.00788802
totalOtherIncomeExpensesNet          14382000
incomeBeforeTax                     -27645000
incomeBeforeTaxRatio               -0.0558138
incomeTaxExpense                            0
```

Im kind of new with python (3 months) so im not sure even of all easy problems..i guess

Thanks for your help

UPDATE

i just did it like this now (even will cost me more time)

i declared also revenue

```
net_income = IS[0]['netIncome']
revenue = IS[0]["revenue"]
```

and calculated like this

```
income_statement['as_%_of_revenue'] = (net_income/revenue)*100
```

looking forward if this causes any further problems what i guess

Data looks like this now

```
                                 current_year  as_%_of_revenue
period                                     FY        -4.920978
revenue                             495308000        -4.920978
costOfRevenue                        43839000        -4.920978
grossProfit                         451469000        -4.920978
grossProfitRatio                     0.911491        -4.920978
researchAndDevelopmentExpenses      101117000        -4.920978
generalAndAdministrativeExpenses    101439000        -4.920978
sellingAndMarketingExpenses         252820000        -4.920978
otherExpenses                               0        -4.920978
operatingExpenses                   455376000        -4.920978
costAndExpenses                     499215000        -4.920978
interestExpense                      38119000        -4.920978
depreciationAndAmortization          12101000        -4.920978
ebitda                              8.194e+06        -4.920978
ebitdaratio                         0.0165432        -4.920978
operatingIncome                    -3.907e+06        -4.920978
operatingIncomeRatio              -0.00788802        -4.920978
totalOtherIncomeExpensesNet          14382000        -4.920978
incomeBeforeTax                     -27645000        -4.920978
incomeBeforeTaxRatio               -0.0558138        -4.920978
incomeTaxExpense                            0        -4.920978
netIncome                           -24374000        -4.920978
```

Comment: can you also add what your final dataframe should look like?

Comment: @PrakashDahal unfortunately there is no final dataframe. It should generate a number to go on with. The final number shall submit the fair value of an asset. The only problem here which arise is, that the division is based on an object (dictionary/class)

Comment: I mean your dataframe should contain new column `"as_%_of_revenue"` according to the last code that you have given, isn't it? I want to see what that values of that column look like

Comment: thats right but it doesnt...if you mean this code:  income_statement['as_%_of_revenue'] = income_statement /income_statement.iloc[0], this arise TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Well I just wnat to see whats might be that column values. Can you calculate it and add a new column, then it will be easy to understand your problem otherwise I dont think I have understand that much

Comment: @PrakashDahal just updated my answer...my goal was to divide net Income/ revenue ..then i just declared revenue like net income and it works

Comment: is your problem solved now? I have just understood your question and know the answer

Comment: @Prakash...its kind of solved but im not sure if im fine with it...if you have an idea, i would be really thankful about your answer

Answer (score 0):

easy ,you can try this"income_statement = income_statement[6:26]".